# Problem with GeoServer GeoWebCache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have a problem. My objective is to do the cache of a WMS service, imagining that I have a layer with a digit ('1' or '2'), and have a style that says for example that '1' is the color blue and '2' is green. My problem is that if I change for example the feature from 1 to 2, the cached files are still in blue and don't update to green. How can I force the erase of the cached files if the features of the service changes?

Comment: You need a way to notify GeoWebCache that the underlying data has changed - how to do that depends on how you change the data and where it is stored.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.